# Getting substring from column in python using apply lambda and str

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column Fib, I am trying to grab a substring from it:

Could anyone please tell me why this code does not work:

```
df['new'] = df['Fib'].apply(lambda x:x.str[2:10])
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

But if i do this, it will work:

```
df['new_col'] = df['Fib'].astype(str).str[2:10]
```

I am trying to solve the above problem with apply+lambda just to get some experience with it.
Thank you

Comment: `df['new'] = df['Fib'].apply(lambda x:x[2:10])` don't use `str` inside the lambda

Comment: My recommendation here would be to *not* use `apply`. Use [slice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) instead

Comment: Using df['new'] = df['Fib'].apply(lambda x:x[2:10]) generated an error: df['new'] = df['Fib'].apply(lambda x:x[2:10])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the `lambda` function you `apply` along the rows of your series will be receiving a string as it appears. Here's an example to illustrate this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num':[1,4,2], 'alpha':['apple','orange','peach']})
df['alpha'].apply(lambda x:type(x))
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Note that [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) methods are only for `Series`, as clearly stated in the documentation:

> Vectorized string functions for Series and Index

So for your example you should avoid using apply. Instead do:

```
df['alpha'].str[2:10]

0     ple
1    ange
2     ach
Name: alpha, dtype: object
```

If what you want is to use `apply` instead as you mention, you simply need `lambda x: x[2:10]` as you are directly slicing the string:

```
df['alpha'].apply(lambda x: x[2:10])
0     ple
1    ange
2     ach
Name: alpha, dtype: object
```