# Remove strings at column based on strings of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this in `pandas` and `python`:

```
    text1       text2
0   sunny       This is a sunny day
1   rainy day   No this day is a rainy day
```

and I want to transform it to this:

```
    text1       text2
0   sunny       This is a day
1   rainy day   No this day is a
```

Therefore, I want to remove some text from `text2` based on `text1` of the same row.

I did this:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x['text2'].str.replace(x['text1'], ''))
```

but I was getting an error:

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

which maybe related to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53986135/9024698.

What is the most efficient way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fast a bit ugly solution is `replace` - but possible multiple whitespaces if need replace per rows by another column:

```
df['text2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['text2'].replace(x['text1'], ''), axis=1)
print (df)
       text1              text2
0      sunny     This is a  day
1  rainy day  No this day is a
```

Solution with split both columns:

```
df['text2'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x['text2'].split() 
                                          if y not in set(x['text1'].split())), axis=1)
```

If need replace by all values of another column better is use solution by @Erfan:

```
df['text2'].str.replace('|'.join(df['text1']), '')
```

Comment: Thank you (upvote). By the way, I am looking for `No this day is a` which is not what you have at your second solution.

Comment: Cant you simply use `df['text2'].str.replace('|'.join(df['text1']), '')`?

Comment: @Erfan, I do not want to replace by all values of another column

Comment: I see, then it makes sense :) @PoeteMaudit

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method :

```
df["text2"]=df["text2"].replace(to_replace=df["text1"],value="",regex=True)
```

**EDIT**:

As metioned by @jezrael, this method does not take into account surounding spaces (as they are not matched by the regex).
However you can tune the regex to avoid some of them adding optional spaces to the pattern for example :

```
df["text2"]=df["text2"].replace(to_replace=df["text1"]+" *",value="",regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your applying your function over column instead of row. Also, `x['text2']` is already a string so no need to call `.str`. With these modifications, you will have:

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: x['text2'].replace(x['text1'], ''), axis=1))
# 0       This is a  day
# 1    No this day is a
```

As you can see, **you only return the `text2` column**.

Here is one example returning the **whole dataframe** processed:

```
# Import module
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"text1": ["sunny", "rainy day"],
                   "text2": ["This is a sunny day", "No this day is a rainy day"]})
print(df)
#        text1                       text2
# 0      sunny         This is a sunny day
# 1  rainy day  No this day is a rainy day

# Function to apply
def remove_word(row):
    row['text2'] = row.text2.replace(row['text1'], '')
    return row

# Apply the function on each row (axis = 1)
df = df.apply(remove_word, axis=1)
print(df)
#        text1              text2
# 0      sunny     This is a  day
# 1  rainy day  No this day is a
```