# How to remove strings from a column matching with strings of another column of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to two dataframes
first one: `df`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sample': ['Sam1', 'Sam2', 'Sam3'],
    'Value': ['ak,b,c,k', 'd,k,e,b,f,a', 'am, x,y,z,a']
})

df1
```

looks as:

```
    Sample  Value
0   Sam1    ak,b,c,k
1   Sam2    d,k,e,b,f,a
2   Sam3    am,x,y,z,a
```

second one: `df2`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Remove': ['ak', 'b', 'k', 'a', 'am']})
df2
```

Looks as:

```
    Remove
0   ak
1   b
2   k
3   a
4   am
```

I want to remove the strings from `df1['Value']` that are matching with `df2['Remove']`

Expected output is:

```
Sample    Value
Sam1      c
Sam2      d,e,f
Sam3      x,y,z
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685860/remove-strings-at-column-based-on-strings-of-another-column) code did not help me

Any help, thanks

Comment: How come your ```m``` was removed for ```Sam3```? since there's no single ```m``` in your ```df2```, but there's ```am```.. Should it be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apply` as a 1 liner

```
df1['Value'] = df1['Value'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x:','.join([i for i in x if i not in df2['Remove'].values]))
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
  Sample   Value
0   Sam1       c
1   Sam2   d,e,f
2   Sam3   x,y,z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply()` to remove items in df1 `Value` column if it is in df2 `Remove` column.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sample': ['Sam1', 'Sam2', 'Sam3'],
    'Value': ['ak,b,c,k', 'd,k,e,b,f,a', 'am, x,y,z,a']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Remove': ['ak', 'b', 'k', 'a', 'am']})

remove_list = df2['Remove'].values.tolist()

def remove_value(row, remove_list):
    keep_list = [val for val in row['Value'].split(',') if val not in remove_list]

    return ','.join(keep_list)

df1['Value'] = df1.apply(remove_value, axis=1, args=(remove_list,))

print(df1)
```

```
  Sample   Value
0   Sam1       c
1   Sam2   d,e,f
2   Sam3   x,y,z
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will help you

```
for index, elements in enumerate(df1['Value']):
    elements = elements.split(',')
    df1['Value'][index] = list(set(elements)-set(df2['Remove']))
```

Just iterate the data frame and get the diff of array with the remove array like this 
The complete code will be sth like this

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sample': ['Sam1', 'Sam2', 'Sam3'],
    'Value': ['ak,b,c,k', 'd,k,e,b,f,a', 'am,x,y,z,a']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Remove': ['ak', 'b', 'k', 'a', 'am']})

for index, elements in enumerate(df1['Value']):
    elements = elements.split(',')
    df1['Value'][index] = list(set(elements)-set(df2['Remove']))

print(df1)
```

**output**

```
  Sample      Value
0   Sam1        [c]
1   Sam2  [e, d, f]
2   Sam3  [y, x, z]
```